# XML Serialization best practice: Make model serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, mvvm

In an application that uses MVVM, MVC,... In which part should I make objects serializable?

As an example, i'm building an application that uses MVVM (wpf), in which i have to serialize the contents of my model to a subsection of a web.config, to allow configuration from within my application.

I have created an XMLService which would handle the serialization of objects , but to make serializing  easier (and more extensible), obviously we can use annotations to determine which properties are attributes etc...

Is it good practice to just make my model serializable? (use annotations to determine which are attributes etc)? I'm guessing making the viewmodel serializable is a bad practice, and it isn't really what i'm planning to do anyway.

Or do I make some form of intermediate model, an XML-model for example.. This seems to be the most extensible way of working, but creates a TON of work when changing the model: requiring updates to Model, ViewModel AND xml-model, which seems to be super error-prone...

Comment: In my opinion you're exactly right; it is the models that should be serializable since they are  more often the "data elements".

Comment: usually you want to serialize **data** - this is the model.

Comment: i create a duplicate of the model classes purely for the purposes of serialization so you don't have all the xml tags in the model class.  that way your model classes don't change if you later decide to serialize to say JSON instead.  It does create extra work, but its results in a clear purpose to each class. And also it means you can have things in your model that aren't serializable that you then convert to something that is (eg a string). i.e. the data and structure of your model classes is not defined by the task of serialization